# Set breakpoint in Racket?

Tags: debugging, scheme, racket

Using Emacs/geiser with Racket (not DrRacket), how could I set a breakpoint and then step through the code, halting at breakpoint(s)? For example, I've got this code:

```
(define (powerset4 lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      '(())
      (append-map (lambda (x)
                    (begin
                      (fprintf (current-output-port) "~s ~s ~s\n" x lst x)
                      (list x (cons (car lst) x))))
                  (powerset4 (cdr lst)))))
```

and I want to stop inside the `begin` sequence to see what's happening and what the values are. It would also be nice to not rely on ye 'ol `printf` tricks either, i.e., track certain parameters as well. Again, I'm in Emacs and using Geiser. Actually, I'd switch to Guile or Chicken (Geiser languages) if I could do this better with them.

Comment: Setting breakpoints, stepping, etc, is functionality typically associated with a debugger or IDE rather than a language. For `#lang racket` the standard debugger is built into DrRacket. Ther is a `debug` module [https://docs.racket-lang.org/debug/index.html?q=debug#%28mod-path._debug%29] and an unstable library [https://docs.racket-lang.org/unstable/Debugging.html?q=debug#%28form._%28%28lib._unstable%2Fdebug..rkt%29._debug%29%29] that can as part of a Racket language program. These might be more managable than "printing".

Comment: @147pm Use the graphical debugger in DrRacket in order to get breakpoints. http://docs.racket-lang.org/drracket/debugger.html

Comment: The question specifically asked for not DrRacket.

Comment: @147pm  sadly, currently the only Racket debugger is built into DrRacket. Although we'd love to also have a command line debugger if you want to write one. :D

Answer (score 2):

As @ben rudgers mentioned, there is a `debug` language (and library) which seems to work fairly well for what you want. I haven't used the other debugging library because the "unstable" warning is somewhat off-putting.

Here's a sample `test.rkt` file, adapted from your program:

```
#lang racket

(require debug/repl)

(define (powerset4 lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      '(())
      (append-map (lambda (x)
                    (begin
                      (list x (cons (car lst) x))
                      (debug-repl) ;; this is the breakpoint that will enter a REPL
                      ))
                  (powerset4 (cdr lst)))))

(powerset4 '(1 2 3))
```

When I do `C-c C-a` to load the file into Geiser, I'm greeted with a REPL that shows that I've entered the debugger. Then I can inspect the values in the current scope and see what's going on.

```
Welcome to Racket v6.6.
racket@> ,enter "/Users/my_username/test.rkt"
-racket@test.rkt> x
'()
-racket@test.rkt> lst
'(3)
-racket@test.rkt>
```

Strangely, (for me at least) when Geiser tried to `auto-complete` the `lst` variable, the REPL hung and killing the `racket` process of the REPL caused Emacs to hang as well. Not exactly sure what that was all about, but this seems to work well aside from that.